# Is there a more efficient way to compare an array of bytes in C

Tags: ios, c

I'm trying to detect if a given file is a ZIP file by looking at the first four bytes.  This is in an iOS app so the file handle stuff is handled by the Cocoa framework, but the actual byte comparison stuff is straight up C, which I don't really know.

```
    unsigned char aBuffer[4];
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
    NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:4];
    [data getBytes:aBuffer];
    if (aBuffer[0] == 0x50 && aBuffer[1] == 0x4b && aBuffer[2] == 0x03 && aBuffer[3] == 0x04) {
        archiveType = ARCHIVE_TYPE_ZIP;
    }
```

It works but strikes me as ungainly. Is there a better way to compare those 4 bytes?  (And yes I know it needs more error checking.)

Comment: `*((unsigned int) aBuffer) == 'PK\3\4'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You chould use [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/). It's like `strcmp`, but for memory.

```
if (memcmp([data bytes],"PK\3\4",4) == 0) {
    // success
}
```

That said, since you're using Objective-C you should be looking for a higher-level implementation than C. I suggest building an NSData with the data you expect, then using `[data isEqual: expectedData]`.

```
NSData *expectedHeader = [NSData dataWithBytes: "PK\3\4" length: 4];
if ([expectedHeader isEqual: data]) {
    // success
}
```

You can also use `isEqualToData:` instead if `isEqual:`. I prefer the short identifier, but `isEqualToData:` is more efficient and throws when exposed to mismatched types.

You're now very near your **intent**, rather than the actual mechanics.

@jsd clarified that he was looking for programmer efficiency, rather than runtime efficiency. But for anyone reading this in the future: Forget about runtime efficiency. How often are you checking for a zip header? Instead, worry about how simple the code is and how many ways it can go wrong. And always favour higher-level abstractions when they fit.

Comment: Add to this something to compare to: `unsigned char referenceBuffer[4] = {0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04};`

Comment: For following normal Cocoa conventions, I'm a big fan of the `NSData -isEqual:` solution. For that matter, you could create a dictionary of first four bytes to file type with suitable `NSData` keys and `NSNumber` values. Would that help make the overall code simpler? It'd be one line to lookup type rather than a bunch of if statements.

Comment: When I said "efficient" I meant programmer-efficient, not runtime-efficient.  Shorter clearer code is always better.  I like your idea of using two NSData's, I didn't realize you could construct them with C literals like that.  That's what I ended up doing.  The only difference is I used isEqualToData: instead of isEqual:.  Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: I actually thought that's what you meant, and I meant to word it so it was obviously for posterity, but I clearly did so poorly. I'll add the `isEqualToData:`; I have been using `isEqual:` because it's shorter and I don't do enough comparisons for the performance to matter.

Comment: Also, I'm not going to add this to the answer, but if you're concerned about the extra allocation you could always add a category for `bytesAreEqualTo:(void*)ptr length:(NSUInteger)length` and use memcmp in there. Categories are great for moving conceptually simple code that ends up looking a little messy.

Answer (score 2):

You could always put `aBuffer` in a `union`, so you can check with just one comparison:

```
union {
  unsigned char asBytes[4];
  uint32_t asInt;
} aBuffer;
...
[data getBytes:aBuffer.asBytes];
if (aBuffer.asInt == 0x504b0304) { ... } // or 0x04034b50, depending on endianness
```

Comment: iPhone and iPad are little endian.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any more efficient way that I can think of.

The compiler will probably do a fine job of optimizing this for you.

And since it is only a single statement that is not in a loop or anything, I am not sure if there is a reason to try to optimize it by hand.

One thing that you could do would be to do an unsigned long compare as in

```
unsigned char fileCheck [4] = {0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04};
unsigned char aBuffer[4];

NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:4];
[data getBytes:aBuffer];

if (*(unsigned long *)aBuffer == *(unsigned long *)fileCheck) {
    // it is a file
    archiveType = ARCHIVE_TYPE_ZIP;
}
```

Comment: I would expect that since both are char arrays that are both being cast to an unsigned long any transformations will be done the same on both variables.  So the result should be equivalence since the characters are in the same order and if the order is changed, the bytes will be moved in the same way.  I do not have an iOS device so am unable to test.  This is a standard way of improving speed in Standard C Library string functions by doing comparisons with more bytes with the same register load and register compare.

Answer (score 0):

That's ungainly but unlikely to be inefficient.

An alternative would be to use C's [`memcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) function. For example:

```
if(!memcmp(aBuffer, "PK\003\004", 4))
{
    archiveType = ARCHIVE_TYPE_ZIP;
}
```

You might also prefer to cut the extra buffer:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:4];
if ([data length] >= 4 && !memcmp([data bytes], "PK\003\004", 4))     
{
    archiveType = ARCHIVE_TYPE_ZIP;
}
```

C (and, hence, Objective-C) guarantees left to right evaluation of if statements and early exit if possible so checking the length first like that will explicitly avoid the `memcmp` wandering out of bounds.

Comment: I meant programmer-efficient (faster to write, clearer to understand) not runtime-efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the following?

```
if (*((unsigned int *) aBuffer) == 'PK\3\4') {
    archiveType = ARCHIVE_TYPE_ZIP;
}
```

This should work on iOS devices like the iPad and iPhone, where data type sizes are consistent.

Those downvoting me must not be familiar with multicharacter literals.

Comment: Your code does not work. First, on iOS, the order of characters in multicharacter literals is reversed from the order in string constants (according to a test I just performed). Second, if you do not have documentation specifying compiler treatment of multicharacter literals, then it is unreliable. Third, this is bad practice in general, due to issues such as the fact that an address of a character array may be poorly aligned for use as the address of an unsigned int, the fact that it is undefined in C allowing the optimizer to alter the code in unpredictable ways, etc.